# How to add multiple sections config parser?

Tags: python, qt, configparser

```
def contador(self):

    estado=self.ui.chbL01
    lugar=self.ui.lineEdit
    global contadorr

    if(estado.isChecked()):
        contadorr=contadorr+1
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(str(contadorr))
        config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
        pedidos=open("pedidos.ini",'w')
        config.add_section(str(contadorr))
        config.write(pedidos)
        pedidos.close()
```

I want to create a section from contador.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QSettings`.

Official docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html

Python version: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/pyqt_qsettings.html